# Move component to another folder

Tags: 2009

I want to move one component from one folder to another folder already created.

```
while (textReader.Read())
{
    textReader.MoveToElement();
    Component comp = tdse.GetComponent(textReader.GetAttribute("ID"), constant_Publication, true, -1);
}
```

I try looking for `comp.Move` but it doesn't exist. Also, I saw that in `comp.Info.Path` there is the path, but if I try to modify it I have the following error:

> Error 7 Property or indexer
>   'Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDS._Info.Path' cannot be assigned to
>   -- it is read only.

What can i do to move the component?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you are using TOM rather than TOM.NET

You need to perform a paste action with the folder you want to get the new item into

Something like

```
objFolder.PasteItem(comp, 1, false)
```

The first parameter is the item you want to paste, the second is an enumerator (EnumTDSCutCopyAction - 1 is cut (move), 0 is copy ) to say if you want to *Copy and Paste* or *Cut and Paste*, and the final one is whether you want to assert a unique name.

In TOM.NET there is a `RepositoryLocalObject.Move()` method.

Comment: I just wanted to add that you should use the enumeration (TDSDefines.EnumTDSCutCopyAction) instead of hard-coding it to "1". It won't change, but it's a good practice regardless :)

Answer (score 12):

in the TOM API you have this method implemented on the Folder as a paste action (in the 2011 TOM.NET API there is a `Component.Move` indeed).

```vb
Folder.PasteItem(ByVal Item As Variant, ByVal action As TDSDefines.EnumTDSCutCopyAction, ByVal makeUnique As Boolean)
```

Parameters

- item - The TOM object or URI representing the item to be pasted.
- action - The action to perform: cut-paste or copy-paste.
- makeUnique - Specifies whether the title of the pasted item should be made unique within the new organizational item.